# Картинка приложения для постинга ссылок

Tags: сервисы, интеграция, разметка, вконтакте

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Для того, чтобы ссылки на мой сайт красиво отображались в социальных сетях, создал специальную картинку - лого. Вот, например, как выгладит ссылка на facebook:

[image]

Картинки слева смотрятся отлично.
Но возникла проблема с контактом. Вот какая ерунда получается:
     [image]

Чтобы картинка появлялась на фэйсбуке, я указал специальный мета-тэг. Существует ли такой тэг чисто для Контакта (тогда я просто укажу там другую картинку)? Может есть другие решения? Желательно без скриптов JS, а то на мобильных браузерах это может стать проблемой.

Answer (score 2):

Эврика!!! Чисто как говориться "на шару" (но я это называю методом научного тыка), ввёл такой url:

```
http://vk.com/share.php?image=http://example.com/webpages/images/logovk3.png&url=http://example.com/news/32
```

т.е. тот, который содержит ключ IMAGE. И всё работает!!!

Надеюсь, кому-то в будущем поможет. Я потратил на поиск решения целых 2 часа.

Comment: Лучше бы вы чётко описали, что ничего не сделали, а с помощью опенграфа заработало. Ну или описали решение, которое применили. Решённая задача — это хорошо, вот только другие не смогут повторить вашего успеха.

Answer (score 1):

ВКонтакте полагается на тот же Open Graph протокол, что и FaceBook. Упоминание нашлось в дебрях вконтактовских док: [для видео](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2) картинку надо указывать через знакомый `<meta og:image`, значит, и просто картинка для сайта указывается так же.

[Где-то](http://habrahabr.ru/company/softline/blog/144946/#comment_4869368) кто-то писал про аналогичный тег `<meta vk:image` — не пробовал.

Comment: попробовал, не работает